# Calculate the perimeter of a circle with a continuously increasing radius

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, circles

I have a circle (if that would even be the correct name for this shape), with a radius function equal to $R=\frac 2\theta + 1$, where $\theta$ is the angle in radians. The domain is between $\theta = 0.25$ and $\theta = 2\pi$.

How do I calculate the total outside perimeter of this shape? I tried to divide it into individual sectors, and find the arc length, but couldn't find a way due to the two radii (in each sector) being different.

The main question is what is a generalised method that could be used to calculate the perimeter of the shape, with an increasing radius (which increases with the angle relative to a starting direction)? The exact function isn't too important.

Comment: Incidentally, you are right that it is incorrect to call that a circle. Just call it "the curve defined by the equation $r=\frac2\theta + 1$ in polar coordinates".

Comment: This curve I believe is called a *lituus* -- it's not a circle. A circle would be given by $r=c,$ with $c$ being a positive constant.

Comment: @Allawonder: this is a [hyperbolic spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_spiral). The [lituus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lituus_(mathematics)) is $r=\frac{c}{\sqrt{\theta}}$.

Comment: @robjohn I see. A misfiring of the rons!

Comment: @robjohn By the way, that raises the question of the family of curves $$r=c\phi^k,$$ where $k$ is an arbitrary *negative* real number.

Answer (score 5):

Remember how one derives the formula for the arc length for $y=f(x)$:
$$L=\int_{x_1,f(x_1)}^{x_2, f(x_2)}dl=\int_{x_1,f(x_1)}^{x_2, f(x_2)}\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx$$
We can start with the same formula, but we switch to polar coordinates:
$$x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta$$
Since our integration variable is $\theta$, you get $$\frac{dx}{d\theta}=\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta-r\sin\theta\\\frac{dy}{d\theta}=\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta$$
Square the above equations and add the together. Then you get $$\left(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right)^2=r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2$$
Then $$L=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2} d\theta$$

Comment: LOL. Sorry @GarethMa.

Answer (score 2):

There are three main ways to describe a curve

- by a cartesian equation $y=f(x)$,
- by parametric equation(s) $x=x(t), \ y=y(t)$,
- by a polar equation $r=r(\theta)$. We are here in this third case with

$$r(\theta)=\frac{2}{\theta}+1$$

Each "way" has its own formulas for the computation of areas, lengths, etc. which IMHO have not to be established again each time one uses them :

In particular, the [length formula (6)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArcLength.html) for polar equations is

$$L=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\sqrt{r^2+\left(\dfrac{dr}{dθ}\right)^2} d\theta$$

Which here becomes :

$$\int_{0.25}^{2 \pi}\frac{\sqrt{(\theta^2+2\theta)^2+4}}{\theta^2}d\theta$$

which has no simple expression... You must use numerical methods for getting an approximate result. I found $16.325196$ with Matlab, which looks good when seeing the curve below (the equivalent of a circle with perimeter $2 \pi R$,  $R\approx 1.5$ + a "line" from $(1.5, 2.3)$ to $(8.5,2)$).

[image]

Comment: Is the numerical result I find (with Matlab) in agreement with yours ?

Comment: Apparently, you do not enjoy the nice, closed form antiderivative ! By the way, how are you doing in this terrible time ? Take care. Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici There is a closed form ? Please give it ! Besides, this strange lockdown time will be followed by even stranger times, France in particular. Some similarities with the strange/terrible May-June-July 1940 period that our parents have told us... Cheers

Comment: I just added a preamble and the (spiral looking) curve.

Comment: The antiderivative would take almost four pages ! A bunch of elliptid integrals of all kinds.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, using $\theta$ as the parameter, one have $x=(\frac 2 {\theta} +1)\cos \theta$ and $y=(\frac 2 {\theta} +1)\sin \theta$. Therefore $$ds=\sqrt{(\frac {dx} {d\theta})^2+(\frac {dy} {d\theta})^2}d\theta=\sqrt{(-2\theta^{-2}\cos\theta-(\frac 2 \theta+1)\sin\theta)^2+(-2\theta^{-2}\sin\theta+(\frac 2 {\theta}+1)\cos\theta)^2}d\theta$$.
Now evaluate the integral $$\int _{0.25} ^{2\pi} ds$$.